# Haskell reference to module

Tags: haskell, module

Is is possible to have reference to module in haskell? I have several modules, each of them expose the same interface(two functions of same name and signature). Is it possible to have a list of such modules, to call function for each module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about defining a data type for the interface? Each module provides a single instance of the datatype and then you can iterate through all instances.

```
-- ModuleInterface.hs
-- Replace types of the functions with actual types
data ModuleInterface = ModuleInterface (Int -> Bool -> Int) (String -> Int)

-- ModuleA.hs
moduleInterface :: ModuleInterface
moduleInterface = ModuleInterface f1 f2
-- Declare f1 and f2

-- ModuleB.hs
moduleInterface :: ModuleInterface
moduleInterface = ModuleInterface f1 f2
-- Declare f1 and f2

-- Main.hs
-- Simple example showing how to "call" all of the functions. If you are doing
-- IO, then you would have to use something like mapM.
transform :: [ModuleInterface] -> Int -> Bool -> String -> [(Int, Int)]
transform interfaces i b s = map f interfaces
    where f (ModuleInterface g h) = (g i b, h s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but name conflicts are usually resolved with simply using qualified imports. In the example below one observes the `S.` and `M.` to explicitly say which module the function or type is in.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.Map as M

mySet :: S.Set Int 
mySet = S.fromList [1,2,3]

myMap :: M.Map String Int 
myMap = M.fromList [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)] 

main = do
  print mySet
  print myMap
  print $ S.member 2 mySet
  print $ M.lookup "c" myMap
```

But it seems from your question that you look for some meta programming solutions, where you have *values* that are modules, say `setModule, mapModule :: Module`, and use getters on it like `getFunctions :: Module -> [Functions]`. I'm certain this doesn't exist since it's not fitting in with a statically typed language. However, you probably can whip something up if you heavily misuse Template Haskell or macros.